# Mapping Coordinates on a Plane Tangent to a Sphere into Cartesian Coordinates in 3D Space

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates, solid-geometry

Before we begin, I must ask you to keep the vocabulary at high school level.

These variables define the point the plane needs to be tangent to – the center of the circle is at the origin.
r - defines the radius of the sphere
Ø<sub>1</sub> – defines the rotation in the x-z axis – can be from 0 to 2π
Ø<sub>2</sub> – defines the rotation in the y axis – can be from 0 to π

[image: Axis of the Sphere]
[image: Showing theta 1 and 2 in 2d with axis]

I have found that I can convert that point on the sphere to Cartesian coordinates using equations.
x<sub>0</sub>=r•cosØ<sub>1</sub>•sinØ<sub>2</sub>
z<sub>0</sub>=r•sinØ<sub>1</sub>•sinØ<sub>2</sub>
y<sub>0</sub>=r•cosØ<sub>2</sub>

These variables define the location of the point to be converted on the 2d plane that is tangent to the sphere.
d<sub>1</sub> – is the x coordinate
d<sub>2</sub> – is the y coordinate

Positive y for the 2d plane is in the vertical direction as much as possible (because the plane is tangent to the sphere), positive x is in the counterclockwise direction looking down on the sphere from positive y in 3d space (or to the right if the plane is on your side of the sphere).

[image: Plane on a Sphere]

The formulas I have made are:

x<sub>1</sub>=x<sub>0</sub>+d<sub>2</sub>•cosØ<sub>1</sub>•cosØ<sub>2</sub>-d<sub>1</sub>•sinØ<sub>1</sub>
z<sub>1</sub>=z<sub>0</sub>+d<sub>2</sub>•sinØ<sub>1</sub>•cosØ<sub>2</sub>+d<sub>1</sub>•cosØ<sub>1</sub>
y<sub>1</sub>=y<sub>0</sub>+d<sub>2</sub>•sinØ<sub>2</sub>

At this point I hope you understand what I am trying to do and can point me to where I’ve gone wrong.

Comment: In your first picture, it looks like your $z$ is pointing backward? By right hand rule, it should point outward. Also, I don't understand "Positive y for the 2d plane is in the vertical direction as much as possible, positive x is in the counterclockwise direction looking down on the sphere from positive y in 3d space." Is your plane parallel to $xz$?

Comment: @KittyL The 2d plane would only be parallel to xz if it were on top of the sphere or on the bottom of the sphere because I am referring to the plane that is parallel to the surface of the sphere. What I meant by that was that the positive y direction is as vertical as possible, as the plane itself would in most cases be at a tilt. As for the z, I put it the way that it is because that is the direction that the y would be pointing if it were just an xy plane. It's probably not "correct", but it seems to make the most sense to me.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand the variables. If you can draw another picture with the 2d plane, that might explain better. Also for the z axis in the first picture, it really depends on where you stand to look at it so that it would be where the y would be pointing if it were xy plane. So better do it in the correct way.

Comment: And by the way, if you only want to find the equation of the plane that is tangent to the sphere, it should just be $x_0x+y_0y+z_0z=r^2$.

Comment: So I drew that picture you asked for and added it. I don't know how to work with an equation of a plane, it should be possible using only geometry and trig.

Comment: OK. I finally understand your question. Some of the words are very confusing though. My answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I did is I changed the axis to a more conventional format.
[image: Axis of Sphere - Working Equation]
All I really did is switch the y and z axis.

To that effect, this is the revised polar-to-cartesian coordinate conversion equations.
x<sub>0</sub>=r•cosØ<sub>1</sub>•sinØ<sub>2</sub>
y<sub>0</sub>=r•sinØ<sub>1</sub>•sinØ<sub>2</sub>
z<sub>0</sub>=r•cosØ<sub>2</sub>

This is the plane that is tangent to the sphere.
[image: Plane that is tangent to sphere]

These are the equations that convert coordinates on the plane into 3d cartesian coordinates.
[image: Working Equation!!]
And the written version (in case you can't load images for some reason)
x<sub>1</sub>=x<sub>0</sub>-d<sub>2</sub>•cosØ<sub>1</sub>•cosØ<sub>2</sub>-d<sub>1</sub>•sinØ<sub>1</sub>
y<sub>1</sub>=y<sub>0</sub>-d<sub>2</sub>•sinØ<sub>1</sub>•cosØ<sub>2</sub>+d<sub>1</sub>•cosØ<sub>1</sub>
z<sub>1</sub>=z<sub>0</sub>+d<sub>2</sub>•sinØ<sub>2</sub>

This is a close-up on the diagrams.
[image: Close-up Diagrams]

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking to find the equation of the plane (or points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ on the plane) that is tangent to the sphere at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

I will following the regular right hand rule, so the $z$ axis in your first picture should point outward. The $\theta_2$ starts from the positive $y$ direction.

So your $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ in spherical coordinates is correct. Then you find the directive with respect to $theta_1,theta_2$ to find the tangent direction.

The new points are

$$ x_1=x_0+d_2\cos{\theta_2}\cos{\theta_1}-d_1\sin{\theta_2}\sin{\theta_1}\\
 z_1=z_0+d_2\cos{\theta_2}\sin{\theta_1}+d_1\sin{\theta_2}\cos{\theta_1}\\
 y_1=y_0-d_1\sin{\theta_2}$$

Comment: I don't know the regular right hand rule. Looking at the xy plane like normal(+x to right, +y up), is the positive z coming towards me or going away from me?

Comment: It points toward you.